# Mock chrome.storage.local functions using Jasmine

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, jasmine

I have the following code in a file named `options.js`. I need to mock it using Jasmine. I need to test whether `chrome.storage.local.set` is called when `save` function is called.

In the spec file I have the following code. But it does not call the chrome function in `options.js` file. Can someone point out the mistake?

```
  beforeEach(function() {
    ctrl = new OptionCtrl(scope);
    chrome: {
      storage: {
        local: {
          set: function() {
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });

  it('should call storage on save', function() {
    spyOn(chrome.storage.local, 'set').and.callThrough();
    ctrl.save({data: 'check'}, 'check');
    expect(chrome.storage.local.set).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

**Update 1**: save function implementation

```
  save(data, successMessage) {
    chrome.storage.local.set(data, (error) => {
      if (error) {
        this.status('Error Occurred. Please refresh.', 1000, 100, 'danger');
      } else {
        this.status(successMessage, 1000, 100, 'success');
      }
    });
  }
```

[Link to the options.js file](https://github.com/ankit-m/mtw_jspm/blob/master/lib/scripts/controllers/options.js) - Line: 122

Comment: What is implementation for `ctrl.save()` method?

Comment: `save` is a function of class `OptionCtrl` which just calls `chrome.storage.local.set(data, callback)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stubbing in Jasmine is easy as:

```js
var chrome = {
  storage: {
    local: {
      set: function() {}
    }
  }
}

function OptionCtrl() {
  this.save = function(data, callbackStr) {
    chrome.storage.local.set(data)
  }
}

describe('OptionCtrl', function() {
  var ctrl;

  beforeEach(function() {
    ctrl = new OptionCtrl({});
  });

  it('calls storage on save', function() {
    spyOn(chrome.storage.local, 'set').and.callThrough();
    var dataStub = {
      data: 'check'
    }

    ctrl.save(dataStub, 'check');

    expect(chrome.storage.local.set).toHaveBeenCalledWith(dataStub);
  });

})
```

```html
<link href="//safjanowski.github.io/jasmine-jsfiddle-pack/pack/jasmine.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//safjanowski.github.io/jasmine-jsfiddle-pack/pack/jasmine-2.0.3-concated.js"></script>
```

Comment: I still get a failed test. It says spy is not called.

Comment: @ankit_m probably you don’t have access to Chrome API in tests ; (